# ionic - export 'IonicStorageModule' was not found in '@ionic/storage'

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to use storage in ionic (based on angular), so I did all that described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/storage/ and import it like this:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

but I get this error:

```
export 'IonicStorageModule' was not found in '@ionic/storage'
```

My ionic version is 6.13.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The use of storage was changed in ionic and now you need to import it as following:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
```

As described in details here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage

Answer (score 10):

For angular need to install as

```
npm install --save @ionic/storage-angular
```

Then

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
```